# How to extract unique substring from a string in Python, when comparing it against another string?

Tags: python, string, duplicates

I have two strings, say 'a' and 'b'. I want to compare 'a' against 'b' and extract only the unique part of 'a'. I could simply check if 'b' is in a and extract. But the issue here is, either string 'a' or 'b' has randomly ignored whitespaces, thus making it slightly difficult.

Here is what I have done so far

```
a = "catsand dogs some other strings"
b = "cats and dogs"

a_no_space = a.replace(" ", "")
b_no_space = b.replace(" ", "")
if(b_no_space in a_no_space and len(a_no_space) > len(b_no_space)):
  unique = a[b_no_space.index(b_no_space)+len(b_no_space):]
```

With this solution, I get the following result

```
s some other strings
```

I don't want that 's' in the beginning. How can I fix this in python?
Does using regex help here? If so how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can convert your search string to a regular expression where spaces are replaced by '\s*' which will accept any number of intermediate spaces between words (including no spaces):

```
a = "catsand dogs some other strings"
b = "cats and dogs"

import re
pattern = r"\s*".join(map(re.escape,re.split("\s+",b))) # r'cats\s*and\s*dogs'

r = re.sub(pattern,"",a) # ' some other strings'
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution that progressively slices the larger string according to the letters of the substring:

```
idx = 0
if len(a) > len(b):
    for letter in b:
        if letter in a and letter != " ":
            a= a[a.index(letter) + 1:]
    print(a)
else:
    for letter in a:
        if letter in b and letter != " ":
            b= b[b.index(letter) + 1:]
    print(b)
```

Comment: Your solution works for this particular scenario. But what if ` a = "catsanddogs some string" b = "cats and dogs" ` ? In that case, the result is ` ome string `

Comment: @silentcobra. You are right.  I came up with a better solution (above) that relies on progressive slicing of the larger string.